Acceptable core leakage
Good morning everyone,
I am currently using an LAPW+lo-code that uses the muffin-tin (MT) approximation, where the electronic wavefunctions $\psi(\mathbf{r})$ are expanded on different basis sets when $\mathbf{r}\in \mathrm{MT}$.
One problem that can occur is so-called core leakage which is to my understanding the amount of charge "leaking" from semi-core states which can not really be considered as pure core states and neither as valence states. In that case, treating them as core states (e.g. completely confined to the muffin-tins) leads to some amount of charge not being suitably confined.
I've read that too high of a core leakage can influence results, but the amount of acceptable leakage differs quite strongly depending on the source I am looking at. Some say  <0.01 per atom is fine, while others suggest $\mathrm{10^{-4}}$ or even lower.
Thus my question is: Is there a rule of thumb on how much core leakage is acceptable? And how can too much leakage influence the caluclation? Wrong total energy or some more subtle effects?

In the LAPW method, valence and core electrons are treated within the DFT self-consistency scheme according to the effective potential in each iteration. But nevertheless, they are separated. Only the valence electron states are represented by the LAPW basis functions, while the core electron states are typically calculated on a mesh within each atom's muffin-tin (MT) sphere.
This separation of core and valence electrons is possible, because the LAPW basis functions are orthogonal to core electron states that are completely confined within a MT sphere. If core electrons are extended beyond the MT sphere boundary, this confinement assumption is broken and as a consequence the above mentioned orthogonality is not as strict any more. The LAPW basis at that point is capable of representing to some extent the core electron states. This representation will be very bad and as a consequence, whatever representation of these states you get, it is related to very high Kohn-Sham eigenenergies. If more and more of the core electron states reach out of the MT sphere, the representation of them by the LAPW basis will become better and better, implying that the eigenenergies of these states will go down. At some point they move below the Fermi energy, which is very bad, because in this situation you occupy these states twice: On the one hand because typically all core electron states are occupied and on the other hand this is now also a valence electron state below the Fermi energy. In such a situation you might get everything from an LAPW program. In the best case your calculation fails. In the worst case you obtain nonsense numbers that look reasonable to a person that is not skeptical enough. According to my experience, you might end up in such a situation if a few percent of an electron reach out of the MT sphere.  But even before entering such a situation, you will see very slight and subtle effects of too extended core electron states on the total energy. For most calculations this is not of relevance, but it is also possible that physical properties will get slightly changed by this, for instance the equilibrium lattice constant, forces, or phonon frequencies may be slightly off. Depending on the precision you need, it may thus be a good idea to make sure that you have considerably less core electron leakage. Another case where you need considerably less core electron leakage is whenever you are using the unoccupied Kohn-Sham states in some calculation beyond obtaining the self-consistent density. An example for this are calculations employing the GW approximation to many-body perturbation theory on top of DFT calculations. In the formalism of such calculations also the unoccupied states contribute.
I once also wrote a text on this for the user documentation of the FLEUR code: https://www.flapw.de/MaX-7.0/documentation/ghostBands/ It may also clarify a few things here.
Also, I could imagine that different "LAPW" codes with their differing typical usage are slightly differently affected by this. My experience comes from a conventional FLAPW code and assumes no related local orbitals. If you also have local orbitals in addition to conventional LAPW basis functions, you may see effects of core-electron leakage much earlier. See for example the vanadium example I discuss in [1]. In APW+lo codes the MT part of the valence basis is also less bound to the rest of the unit cell. I would thus assume that you also need to have less core electron leakage for such codes.
[1]: G. Michalicek et al., "Elimination of the linearization error and improved basis-set convergence within the FLAPW method", Computer Physics Communications 184, 2670 (2013) https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cpc.2013.07.002

Thanks for the answer, and from an expert on the topic nonetheless! Just to clarify: When you say "if a few percent of an electron reach out of the MT sphere", you mean per atom, right? So in an extended system, leakage above, say, 10% is fine if leakage per atom is <1% because it is an extensive quantity like total energy?

The statement is meant to be "for any atom". There is no averaging over the unit cell and there is also no accumulation over the unit cell.
